# Syntax error with UPDATE statement in MS-ACCESS VBA

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am new to **MS-ACCESS** and **SQL**.  I am trying to update a field in a linked SQL table but I keep getting

```
3075 Syntax Error.
```

PartData is the linked table
What am I missing?

```
Private Sub REVISE_Click()
On Error GoTo REVISE_Click_Err
'
'***** Define Variables *****
Dim strSQL1 As String 
Dim strSQL2 As String
'
'***** Set Default Values *****
strSQL1 = "Delete * From Inspector"
strSQL2 = "UPDATE PartData SET SpecialNote = " & SpecNotes & " WHERE PartNo= '" & PartNumberSearch & "'"
'
'***** Clear Inspector Values ***** 
CurrentDb.Execute strSQL1, dbFailOnError 
CurrentDb.Execute strSQL2, dbFailOnError
'
DoCmd.Quit acPrompt 
'
REVISE_Click_Exit:
   Exit Sub 
'
REVISE_Click_Err:
   MsgBox Error$ 
   Resume EXIT_Click_Exit
'
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're building query from VBA. You then have a quote issue, since SpecNotes is obviously a string. Try this:

```
strSQL2 = "UPDATE PartData SET SpecialNote = '" & SpecNotes & "' WHERE PartNo= '" & PartNumberSearch & "'"
```

I also think that you could improve your query by using parameters, but that could be another question, and you should then show a bit more of your code, so we can see the context. Note that, without parameters, `strSQL2` could produce unexpected results if `SpecNote` contains quotes.

Comment: Private Sub REVISE_Click()
On Error GoTo REVISE_Click_Err
    '***** Define Variables *****
Dim strSQL1 As String
Dim strSQL2 As String
'
'***** Set Default Values *****
strSQL1 = "Delete * From Inspector"
strSQL2 = "UPDATE PartData SET SpecialNote = " & SpecNotes & " WHERE PartNo= '" & PartNumberSearch & "'"
'
'***** Clear Inspector Values *****
CurrentDb.Execute strSQL1, dbFailOnError
CurrentDb.Execute strSQL2, dbFailOnError
'
    DoCmd.Quit acPrompt


REVISE_Click_Exit:
    Exit Sub

REVISE_Click_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume EXIT_Click_Exit

End Sub

Comment: @Tombo Can't you edit your question and include your code in it ?

Answer (score 0):

Patrick,
      Sorry, still learning.  Please see code below.

```
Private Sub REVISE_Click()
On Error GoTo REVISE_Click_Err
'
'***** Define Variables *****
Dim strSQL1 As String 
Dim strSQL2 As String
'
'***** Set Default Values *****
strSQL1 = "Delete * From Inspector"
strSQL2 = "UPDATE PartData SET SpecialNote = " & SpecNotes & " WHERE PartNo= '" & PartNumberSearch & "'"
'
'***** Clear Inspector Values ***** 
CurrentDb.Execute strSQL1, dbFailOnError 
CurrentDb.Execute strSQL2, dbFailOnError
'
DoCmd.Quit acPrompt 
'
REVISE_Click_Exit:
   Exit Sub 
'
REVISE_Click_Err:
   MsgBox Error$ 
   Resume EXIT_Click_Exit
'
End Sub
```